# Why is my jqGrid dropdown filter removing the column values?

Tags: jquery, filter, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid with the filterToolbar enabled. For one column, Status, I wanted to have a dropdown filter with preset options rather than a free text filter.

What the column looks like in the colModel:

```
colModel: [ 
    ...
    {name: 'status', label: 'Status', formatter: 'select', stype: 'select', searchoptions: {value: ':All;ACTIVE:Active;INACTIVATED:Inactive'}},
    ...
  ],
```

The filter actually works, but the values in the status column are all blank. So when I select "Active" from the filter, all the rows with a Status value of "ACTIVE" are displayed, but it doesn't actually display anything in the Status column.

Here's what the column looks like with "All" selected (and actually displaying all rows regardless of status):

[image]

Why are the status values hidden?

Comment: please include in every question about jqGrid: the version of jqGrid which you use and the fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)

Comment: @Oleg - free jqGrid, version 4.6.0

Comment: The first version of my jqGrid fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid)) is 4.8.0. I started the fork exist after Tony changed the license agreement (see [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438)) and removing other contributes from JavaScript files. Thus the correct product name for version 4.6.0 is "jqGrid" and **the correct names for versions higher as 4.7 are "free jqGrid", "Guriddo jqGrid JS" or the name of some other fork of jqGrid**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `formatter: 'select'` which required either to define `editoptions` with `value` property or to define `formatoptions` with `value` property. Try to add

```
editoptions: {value: 'ACTIVE:Active;INACTIVATED:Inactive'}}
```

to the definition of the column `status`. Be careful to use the values in the input data for the column if you use `formatter: 'select'`. I mean that the input data for the column `status` have to be the values `"ACTIVE"` or `"INACTIVATED"` instead of `"Active"` or `"Inactive"`, which will be displayed in the grid.

Comment: Thanks. Due to your answer I realized I can just remove `formatter:'select'` altogether. It's working now. (It's a great plugin, but I'm finding the docs very unclear.) Once we're at it, how can I configure it so that the column actually displays "Active" and "Inactive" rather than "ACTIVE" and "INACTIVATED"?

Comment: @froadie: You are welcome! To display "Active" and "Inactive" rather than "ACTIVE" and "INACTIVATED" you need just use `formatter: 'select', editoptions: {value: 'ACTIVE:Active;INACTIVATED:Inactive'}}`. See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#formatter_type_select).